# How to install Ubuntu 12.04 within Windows 7 with a CD image of ubuntu (without use of an external CD/USB)?

Tags: windows-7, wubi, cd-image

The wubi installer that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't allow one to install ubuntu within windows. I downloaded the Wubi installer available here [Ubuntu Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

This howerver doesnt allow me to install with the existing image that I downloaded earlier. It downloads ubuntu afresh prior to installing.

Is there a way to install it with the existing CD image and **WITHOUT** use of an external CD/DVD (too lazy to buy one :P)

I used to be able to do this with the earlier versions of Ubuntu just by mounting the CD image as a drive in windows... and the installation would complete in minutes!

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to mount the CD image. Wubi.exe - when run from a CD (or mounted CD image) - no longer supports the 'Install inside Windows' option. Unless you supply `--force-wubi` as a command line option. All you need to do is place wubi.exe in the same folder as the desktop CD ISO before running wubi. If it starts to download a new ISO then there is something wrong with your one - check the log file for details (in the `%TEMP%` folder, called `wubi-12.04-revxxx.log`

Answer (score 3):

The procedure from bcbc's comment works perfectly:

> There is absolutely no reason to mount the CD image. Wubi.exe - when
>   run from a CD (or mounted CD image) - no longer supports the 'Install
>   inside Windows' option. Unless you supply `--force-wubi` as a command
>   line option. All you need to do is place wubi.exe in the same folder
>   as the desktop CD ISO before running wubi. If it starts to download a
>   new ISO then there is something wrong with your one - check the log
>   file for details (in the `%TEMP%` folder, called `wubi-12.04-revxxx.log` –
>   bcbc Jun 1 at 17:50

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html Download and install.
2. Then go to the iso that you downloaded.
3. Right click and click mount. Do not click anything on auto start.
4. Go to my computer.
5. Right click on the ubuntu install drive. Click open folder.
6. Then open the wubi install program. Proceed with installation.

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Answer (score 0):

You can still mount the image using any virtual CD software, like PowerISo, or Virtual CD, or Magic ISO and do that same thing.  You have to create a Virtual Cd Drive to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As told by Mitch you need to install a virtual cd software

Install `DAEMON Tools Lite` from [here](http://www.disc-tools.com/download/daemon)
Its a free version with no usage limit

It will help you create a virtual drive for you

Mount the iso you downloaded with the software. It will then autoplay

Then choose `install inside windows` as the install option.

Done. It will install Ubuntu as wubi.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the downloaded ISO image
2. copy and paste the ISO image into the extracted folder and then launch the Wubi installer.