# Install Ubuntu within Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wubi

Couple of years back I was using Ubuntu installed within Windows 7 OS. Back then Ubuntu version was 10.04.

Today, I downloaded Ubuntu 64-bit Live Disc and when I try to install I do not understand how to install within Windows 7. So, any day later if I need to uninstall Ubuntu I can do by uninstalling via wubi.

Somehow I do not find those options now. What am I missing?

It's a DELL Inspiron laptop running Windows 7 Home edition.

Well, more information on the issue:
I have downloaded the disk image file: `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso`
and burnt it to a physical disc.

Upon starting `wubi.exe` these are the first two views I see:

[image]

and then:

[image]

I do not understand what is going wrong! :-) :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu 12.04 within Windows 7 with a CD image of ubuntu (without use of an external CD/USB)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145071/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-within-windows-7-with-a-cd-image-of-ubuntu-without)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What CD (iso) did you download exactly ? It should contain a file "wubi.exe". Put the iso on a flash drive or CD and run wubi.exe

Alternately, you can use the wubi page directly:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: It has the wubi.exe. But it is not allowing me to install within Windows. Its ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso which is downloaded

Comment: Edited my question with more information.

Comment: This ends up being a duplicate then, see the question I gave you.

Comment: That solves the issue. Using wubi found on disk did not work. But getting it from the link above in your post works.